# Sqlalchemy - One to Many Users to Location

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

hope all is well. I'm having difficulty trying to figure out how to write this db functionality with flask and SQLALCHEMY.

**I want to be able to register a user with a site that will already be existing in  the database.**

When registering them I want the route to be able to assign that user to the site model in the db. **Reason I want to do this is so I can later send a message to all users connected to a particular site, or a message to all users for all sites.**

**This is my User and Site models currently**:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
site = db.Column(db.String())
username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
adminstatus = db.Column(db.Boolean)
user_data = db.relationship('Rma', backref='userdata', lazy=True)
# sites = db.relationship('Sites', secondary=usertosite, backref=db.backref('sites', lazy='dynamic'))

def __repr__(self):
    return f"User('{self.username}, '{self.email}')"

class Sites(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
sitename = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
contractstart = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
contractend = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
hwkey = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
stations = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
printers = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
remprinters = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
bof = db.Column(db.Boolean())
processor = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
giftopt = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
```

**Here is my register form**

```
# REGISTER NEW USER
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_pw = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(site = form.site.data, username = form.username.data, email = form.email.data, password = hashed_pw, adminstatus= form.admin_status.data)
        db.create_all()
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f"{form.username.data} has been added!")
        return redirect(url_for('dash'))

    return render_template('register.html', name = 'login', form=form)
```

I'm not sure how I can do this considering usually when I add a form to a database I add all of the form elements to the specific model. If I try a one to many relationship I would have to assign the Sites model with all of its elements along with the particular user which is not Ideal because the site will already be created in db. I'm a super noob and I'm probably missing some steps but please assist if possible. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a foreign key.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    ...
    site = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sites.id'))
```

Then when you enter `User` information into the database you supply the primary key id of the site that exists as a `Sites`. You can either do this in your route or provide an initialisation override function that does this based on the keyword, for example:

```
class User(..):
    ...
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if 'site' in kwargs:
             site_id = db.session.query(Sites).filter(Sites.sitename == kwargs['site']).one().id
             kwargs['site'] = site_id
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Note that I don't think mySQL or SQLite enforces foreign key consistency by default, which personally I find annoying meaning you can get NULL entries in yoru database when you might not expect them, however POSTGRES does enforce it I believe. There are things you can do in sqlalchemy to enforce foreign key consistency in mySQL and SQLlite, however.

Comment: Allowing NULL is a bit different from enforcing referential integrity. Postgresql does allow NULL in a foreign key column(s), if the columns are nullable. SQLite is the one that does not even enforce referential integrity, unless told to do so using the suitable pragma. Not sure, but perhaps MyISAM tables in MySQL do not enforce referential integrity either, but isn't InnoDB the norm these days?

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I needed. I couldn’t figure out how I would supply the primary key id of the particular site in the sites database. But it looks like searching by keyword is what I need ... which I can also do in the route correct?